# IntelliJ GLSL Support

Tags: intellij-idea, glsl

I use IntelliJ IDEA to create a 3d graphics application, I installed GLSL Support plug-in and that gives me some errors in the glsl code:

```
1 #version 330
2 
3 layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
4 layout (location = 1) in vec2 uv;
5 layout (location = 2) in vec3 normal;
6 
7 out vec3 n;
8 out vec2 uvs;
9 uniform mat4 VP;
10 uniform mat4 M;
11 
12 void main()
13 {
14    uvs = uv;
15    n = normalize((vec4(normal, 1.0) * M).xyz);
16    gl_Position = VP * M * vec4(position, 1.0);
17 }
```

The errors are:

Lines 3,4,5: Expected a type specifier, Expected and identifier, Missing ')' after function prototype, Unexpected token ')', Unexpected token '='.

The shader don't work in the app so i guess its something wrong with it, but I can't see what.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GLSL support plugin was last updated in 2012, and the `layout (location = 0)` syntax seems to be a fairly new feature in GLSL. Most likely the plugin is simply unable to parse the syntax, and the reason why your shader doesn't work is not related to the highlighting that you see.

Comment: No idea. Never used GLSL.